# Count the amount of likes a user received on each post sql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, count

I have two tables. Likes table which contains it's like_id (PK), vole_id, user_id, and created_at timestamp. And another table called voles that contain vole_id (PK), and user_id, as well as a bunch of other columns that will not matter for this problem.

The user_id for the voles tables is the person who posted. I want to get the amount of likes a person has on all their voles combined to show in their profile page.

voles table: [image: voles table]

likes table: [image]

Of course there will be more than one post for a user and more than one like on each post. In this case, user_id 21 has 1 like on vole_id 28.

I honestly don't know where to start, I know the basics of SQL, but I'm still not the best at it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to count records in the `likes` table joining it with `voles` filtering by `user_id`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM likes l
JOIN voles v on (l.vole_id=v.vole_id)
WHERE v.user_id=21 // here is a user id for whom we count all likes
```